# How to acces a global JS-Object in another .js-File

Tags: javascript

How do i acces an object which was initialized in my HTML-Document?

My HTML-Document looks like this:

```
    ...

<script type="text/javascript" id="controller">var controller = false;</script>

    ...

<body onload="controller = new CTRLclass()">

    ....
```

How do I call controller.doAMethod() in an external Javascript-File using DOM-Operations or simmilar?

edit:
PPL, i have many .js-Files and my controller is creating an instance of another class in his constructor. In the created instance of the class i need acces to the controller to call an update-Function.
Like: controller -> creates instance of class.
class -> needs to call controller.update().
How do i acces controller in 'class' - Thats all

THX!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the onload tag to initiate onload tasks. Just put this is the external javascript file:

```
var controller = false;
function Init(){
    controller = new CTLRclass;
}
function addEvent(el, eType, fn, uC) {
    var uC = uC || true;
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(eType, fn, uC);
        return true;
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        return el.attachEvent('on' + eType, fn);
    } else {
        el['on' + eType] = fn;
    }
}
addEvent(window, 'load', Init);
```

Comment: Always makes it look verbose :(. Feel free to recommend [`ender`](http://ender.no.de/#intro) as a lightweight event handling library alternative. `$(el).bind("load", Init)`

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't envisage why you would want to do the above. Simply strip out all of the Javascript in the above, so all you have is:

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js"></script>

...

<body>

....
```

And in myjsfile.js do somthing like

```
window.onload = function(){
    var controller = new CTRLclass();
}
```

If it must be global, then you can move it outside of the onload function:

```
var controller = false
window.onload = function(){
    controller = new CTRLclass();
}
```

Use of jQuery would make it more elegant, of course, as you wouldn't risk overriding any existing onloads:

```
var controller = false
$(document).ready(function(){
    controller = new CTRLclass();
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend `window.contoller = new CTRLclass();`

Comment: @Raynos - Nice, using expando properties on the window object.